# If $A$ is measurable then so is $\alpha A$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm struggling to show this fact. I have already shown that $m(\alpha A) = |\alpha|A$ and I now need to show that $\alpha A$ is measurable. So far I have:

Take an arbitrary subset $E \subset R$ then:
$$m(E \cap \alpha A) + m(E \cap (\alpha A)^c) = m(\alpha  (E \cap A)) + m(\alpha(E \cap (A)^c)) = |\alpha|m(E)$$ as $A$ is measurable.

But now I have an extra $\alpha$ and I want to show that actually this equals $m(E)$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: *Outer* measure $m^*$. $m^*(E\cap\alpha A) + m^*(E\cap (\alpha A)^c)=\cdots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
m^*(E\cap\alpha A)+m^*(E\cap (\alpha A)^c)=m^*(E\cap\alpha A)+m^*(E\cap \alpha(A^c))=
$$

$$
m^*(\alpha(\alpha^{-1}E\cap A))+m^*(\alpha(\alpha^{-1}E\cap(A^c)))=\cdots
$$